# Delete Entry from database on clicking delete button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have added a delete button on my point of sale module.In purchase tab when i click delete it doesn't delete my entry from database.I need help for deleting purchase entry from database whenever i click on delete button.

```
<?php
include_once("init.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>POSNIC - Stock</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <!---->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Optimize for mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <!-- jQuery & JS files -->
    <?php include_once("tpl/common_js.php"); ?>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>


    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        <!--
        // Nannette Thacker http://www.shiningstar.net
        function confirmSubmit() {
            var agree = confirm("Are you sure you wish to Delete this Entry?");
            if (agree)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        function confirmDeleteSubmit() {
            var flag = 0;
            var field = document.forms.deletefiles;
            for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                if (field[i].checked == true) {
                    flag = flag + 1;

                }

            }
            if (flag < 1) {
                alert("You must check one and only one checkbox!");
                return false;
            } else {
                var agree = confirm("Are you sure you wish to Delete Selected Record?");
                if (agree)

                    document.deletefiles.submit();
                else
                    return false;

            }
        }
        function confirmLimitSubmit() {
            if (document.getElementById('search_limit').value != "") {

                document.limit_go.submit();

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }


        function checkAll() {

            var field = document.forms.deletefiles;
            for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
                field[i].checked = true;
        }

        function uncheckAll() {
            var field = document.forms.deletefiles;
            for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
                field[i].checked = false;
        }
        // -->
    </script>
    <script>


        /*$.validator.setDefaults({
         submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
         });*/
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // validate signup form on keyup and submit
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 200
                    },
                    address: {
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 500
                    },
                    contact1: {
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 20
                    },
                    contact2: {
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 20
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: {
                        required: "Please enter a supplier Name",
                        minlength: "supplier must consist of at least 3 characters"
                    },
                    address: {
                        minlength: "supplier Address must be at least 3 characters long",
                        maxlength: "supplier Address must be at least 3 characters long"
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- TOP BAR -->
<?php include_once("tpl/top_bar.php"); ?>
<!-- end top-bar -->


<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header-with-tabs">

    <div class="page-full-width cf">

        <ul id="tabs" class="fl">
            <li><a href="dashboard.php" class="dashboard-tab">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_sales.php" class="sales-tab">Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_customers.php" class=" customers-tab">Customers</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_purchase.php" class="active-tab purchase-tab">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_supplier.php" class=" supplier-tab">Supplier</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_product.php" class=" stock-tab">Stocks / Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_payments.php" class="payment-tab">Payments / Outstandings</a></li>
            <li><a href="view_report.php" class="report-tab">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end tabs -->

        <!-- Change this image to your own company's logo -->
        <!-- The logo will automatically be resized to 30px height. -->
        <a href="#" id="company-branding-small" class="fr"><img src="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logo'])) {
                echo "upload/" . $_SESSION['logo'];
            } else {
                echo "upload/posnic.png";
            } ?>" alt="Point of Sale"/></a>

    </div>
    <!-- end full-width -->

</div>
<!-- end header -->


<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="content">

    <div class="page-full-width cf">

        <div class="side-menu fl">

            <h3>Stock Purchase</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="add_purchase.php">Add Purchase</a></li>
                <li><a href="view_purchase.php">View Purchase </a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end side-menu -->

        <div class="side-content fr">

            <div class="content-module">

                <div class="content-module-heading cf">

                    <h3 class="fl">Purchase</h3>
                    <span class="fr expand-collapse-text">Click to collapse</span>
                    <span class="fr expand-collapse-text initial-expand">Click to expand</span>

                </div>
                <!-- end content-module-heading -->

                <div class="content-module-main cf">


                    <table>
                        <form action="" method="post" name="search">
                            <input name="searchtxt" type="text" class="round my_text_box" placeholder="Search">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Search" type="submit" class="my_button round blue   text-upper"
                                               value="Search">
                        </form>
                        <form action="" method="get" name="limit_go">
                            Page per Record<input name="limit" type="text" class="round my_text_box" id="search_limit"
                                                  style="margin-left:5px;"
                                                  value="<?php if (isset($_GET['limit'])) echo $_GET['limit']; else echo "10"; ?>"
                                                  size="3" maxlength="3">
                            <input name="go" type="button" value="Go" class=" round blue my_button  text-upper"
                                   onclick="return confirmLimitSubmit()">
                        </form>

                        <form name="deletefiles" action="delete.php" method="post">

                            <input type="hidden" name="table" value="stock_entries">
                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="view_purchase.php">
                            <input type="button" name="selectall" value="SelectAll"
                                   class="my_button round blue   text-upper" onClick="checkAll()"
                                   style="margin-left:5px;"/>
                            <input type="button" name="unselectall" value="DeSelectAll"
                                   class="my_button round blue   text-upper" onClick="uncheckAll()"
                                   style="margin-left:5px;"/>
                            <input name="dsubmit" type="button" value="Delete Selected"
                                   class="my_button round blue   text-upper" style="margin-left:5px;"
                                   onclick="return confirmDeleteSubmit()"/>


                            <table>
                                <?php


                                $SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(stock_id) FROM  stock_entries where type='entry'";

                                if (isset($_POST['Search']) AND trim($_POST['searchtxt']) != "") {

                                    $SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(stock_id) FROM  stock_entries WHERE stock_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_supplier_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_id LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR date LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR type LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' AND type='entry'";


                                }

                                $tbl_name = "stock_entries";        //your table name

                                // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?

                                $adjacents = 3;


                                /*

                                   First get total number of rows in data table.

                                   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.

                                */

                                $query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stock_id) as num FROM $tbl_name where type='entry'";
                                if (isset($_POST['Search']) AND trim($_POST['searchtxt']) != "") {

                                    $query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stock_id) as num FROM stock_entries WHERE stock_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_supplier_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_id LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR date LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR type LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' and type='entry'";


                                }
                                $total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db->connection, $query));

                                $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];


                                /* Setup vars for query. */

                                $targetpage = "view_stock_entries.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)

                                $limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page
                                if (isset($_GET['limit']))
                                    $limit = $_GET['limit'];

                                $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

                                if ($page)

                                    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;            //first item to display on this page

                                else

                                    $start = 0;                                //if no page var is given, set start to 0


                                /* Get data. */

                                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(stock_id) FROM stock_entries where type='entry' ORDER BY date desc LIMIT $start, $limit  ";

                                if (isset($_POST['Search']) AND trim($_POST['searchtxt']) != "") {

                                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(stock_id) FROM stock_entries WHERE stock_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_supplier_name LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR stock_id LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR date LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' OR type LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchtxt'] . "%' and type='entry' ORDER BY date desc LIMIT $start, $limit";


                                }

                                $result = mysqli_query($db->connection, $sql);


                                /* Setup page vars for display. */

                                if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    //if no page var is given, default to 1.

                                $prev = $page - 1;                            //previous page is page - 1

                                $next = $page + 1;                            //next page is page + 1

                                $lastpage = ceil($total_pages / $limit);        //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.

                                $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                        //last page minus 1


                                /*

                                    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object.

                                    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.

                                */

                                $pagination = "";

                                if ($lastpage > 1) {

                                    $pagination .= "<div >";

                                    //previous button

                                    if ($page > 1)

                                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$prev&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination >Previous</a>";

                                    else

                                        $pagination .= "<span class=my_pagination>Previous</span>";


                                    //pages

                                    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up

                                    {

                                        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {

                                            if ($counter == $page)

                                                $pagination .= "<span class=my_pagination>$counter</span>";

                                            else

                                                $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$counter&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$counter</a>";

                                        }

                                    } elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some

                                    {

                                        //close to beginning; only hide later pages

                                        if ($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {

                                            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++) {

                                                if ($counter == $page)

                                                    $pagination .= "<span class=my_pagination>$counter</span>";

                                                else

                                                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$counter&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$counter</a>";

                                            }

                                            $pagination .= "...";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$lpm1&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$lpm1</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$lastpage&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$lastpage</a>";

                                        } //in middle; hide some front and some back

                                        elseif ($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=1&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>1</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=2&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>2</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "...";

                                            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {

                                                if ($counter == $page)

                                                    $pagination .= "<span  class=my_pagination>$counter</span>";

                                                else

                                                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$counter&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$counter</a>";

                                            }

                                            $pagination .= "...";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$lpm1&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$lpm1</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$lastpage&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$lastpage</a>";

                                        } //close to end; only hide early pages

                                        else {

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$view_purchase.php?page=1&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>1</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "<a href=\"$view_purchase.php?page=2&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>2</a>";

                                            $pagination .= "...";

                                            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {

                                                if ($counter == $page)

                                                    $pagination .= "<span class=my_pagination >$counter</span>";

                                                else

                                                    $pagination .= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>$counter</a>";

                                            }

                                        }

                                    }


                                    //next button

                                    if ($page < $counter - 1)

                                        $pagination .= "<a href=\"view_purchase.php?page=$next&limit=$limit\" class=my_pagination>Next</a>";

                                    else

                                        $pagination .= "<span class= my_pagination >Next</span>";

                                    $pagination .= "</div>\n";

                                }

                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Stock Id</th>
                                    <th>Stock Name</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Supplier</th>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                    <th>Edit /Delete</th>
                                    <th>Select</th>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php $i = 1;
                                $no = $page - 1;
                                $no = $no * $limit;

                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                                    $entryid = $row['stock_id'];
                                    $line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM stock_entries WHERE stock_id='$entryid' ");

                                    $mysqldate = $line->date;

                                    $phpdate = strtotime($mysqldate);

                                    $phpdate = date("d/m/Y", $phpdate);

                                    ?>

                                    <tr>

                                        <td></td>

                                        <td width="100"><?php echo $line->stock_id; ?></td>
                                        <td width="100"><?php echo $line->stock_name; ?></td>


                                        <td width="100"><?php echo $phpdate; ?></td>

                                        <td width="100"><?php echo $line->stock_supplier_name; ?></td>
                                        <td width="100"><?php echo $line->subtotal; ?></td>


                                        <td>
                                            <a href="update_purchase.php?sid=<?php echo $entryid; ?>&table=stock_entries&return=view_purchase.php"
                                               class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit">
                                            </a>
                                            <a onclick="return confirmSubmit()"
                                               href="delete.php?id=<?php echo isset($row['id']) ? $row['id'] : 0; ?>&table=stock_entries&return=view_purchase.php"
                                               class="table-actions-button ic-table-delete"></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox"
                                                   value="<?php echo isset($row['id']) ? $row['id'] : 0; ?>"
                                                   name="checklist[]" id="check_box"/></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $i++;
                                } ?>
                                <tr>

                                    <td align="center">
                                        <div style="margin-left:20px;"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>


                </div>
            </div>



</body>
</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include_once "init.php";
// Use session variable on this page. This function must put on the top of page.
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['usertype'] != 'admin') { // if session variable "username" does not exist.
    header("location: index.php?msg=Please%20login%20to%20access%20admin%20area%20!"); // Re-direct to index.php
} else {

    error_reporting(0);
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['table'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $tablename = $_GET['table'];
        $return = $_GET['return'];

        if ($tablename == "stock_entries") {
            $difference = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT quantity FROM stock_entries WHERE id=$id");

            $name = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT stock_name FROM stock_entries WHERE id=$id");
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stock_entries where id > $id");
            while ($line2 = $db->fetchNextObject($result)) {
                $osd = $line2->opening_stock - $difference;
                $csd = $line2->closing_stock - $difference;
                $cid = $line2->id;
                $db->execute("UPDATE stock_entries SET opening_stock=" . $osd . ",closing_stock=" . $csd . " WHERE id=$cid");

            }
            $total = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT quantity FROM stock_avail WHERE name='$name'");
            $total = $total - $difference;
            $db->execute("UPDATE stock_avail SET quantity=$total WHERE name='$name'");
        }

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $db->execute("DELETE FROM $tablename WHERE id=$id");

        header("location: $return?msg=Record Deleted Successfully!&id=$id");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['table']) && isset($_POST['checklist'])) {
        $data = $_REQUEST['checklist'];
        $tablename = $_POST['table'];
        $return = $_REQUEST['return'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            $db->execute("DELETE FROM $tablename WHERE id=$data[$i]");
        }
        header("location: $return?msg=Record Deleted Successfully!");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['return'])) {
        header("location: $return");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your delete query? I am not able to find in your code

Comment: On line no 502 DeleteSubmit() is called which is at line 27

Comment: This is `JS` function. I am asking about your mysql query which is required for deleting record from `DB`

Comment: Now i edit the code , u can see now delete.php file...table name is stock_entries

Comment: it would have been great if you had put only those codes which are necessary.. for me its very boring to go through all your code.. I m not generalizing

Comment: Now i had put necessary code ,u can review it in delete.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for taking intrest.I have done it by following way

```
if ($tablename == "stock_entries") {
            $difference = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT quantity FROM stock_entries WHERE id=$id");
            $sid = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT stock_id FROM stock_entries WHERE id=$id");
            $id = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT id FROM stock_entries WHERE salesid='$sid'");

            $name = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT stock_name FROM stock_entries WHERE id=$id");
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stock_entries where id > $id");
            while ($line2 = $db->fetchNextObject($result)) {
                $osd = $line2->opening_stock - $difference;
                $csd = $line2->closing_stock - $difference;
                $cid = $line2->id;
                $db->execute("UPDATE stock_entries SET opening_stock=" . $osd . ",closing_stock=" . $csd . " WHERE id=$cid");


            }
            //echo "purchase $name";
            $total = $db->queryUniqueValue("SELECT quantity FROM stock_avail WHERE name='$name'");
            $total = $total - $difference;
            $db->execute("UPDATE stock_avail SET quantity=$total WHERE name='$name'");
            $db->execute("DELETE FROM $tablename WHERE id=$id");
                        $db->execute("DELETE FROM $tablename WHERE id=$id");


        }
```